# requestWhenInUseAuthorization and requestAlwaysAuthorization

Tags: ios, swift, plist, cllocationmanager

I have this code on plist:

```
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key> <string>Usage</string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription</key> <string>WhenIn</string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key> <string>Always</string>
```

and this one on viewDidLoad of a viewController:

```
 self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
 self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
```

But requestWhenInUseAuthorization() alert isn't appearing. Only to "use on background". Is this normal? What can be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: If you use `requestAlwaysAuthorization`,you do not need to `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`,because,"always" include the case of in use and background

Answer (score 0):

Your "NSLocationWhenInUsageDescription" key in the plist is wrong change it to "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription".

Also the order of the requests will effect what alert the system will present to the user because it will present only the first request alert ("When in use" in your case) but it **will add both of them to the settings** and will **select the first one you requested**.

Hope it helps.